# A word that encapsulates both "person" and "group" (for people going on stage at an event)

Tags: word-choice

At a conference, a talk can be done by a speaker (person) or multiple speakers (group of persons).
At a festival, a live set can be played by an artist (person) or a band (group of persons)

What's a word that would fit the following sentence regardless of the talk/set being done/performed by a person or a group?

> The ____ will be on stage at 2PM on Thursday.

I've thought of “performer” but it wouldn't fit for a group.

Comment: The ***talent*** or ***act***.

Comment: The presentation/performance will begin at 2PM on Thursday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Guest(s)* is one possibility as a universal descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

*the entertainment* could be singular or plural.

Comment: You probably mean *entertainment*

Comment: Well at least I've learned that I use 'entrap' wrong 90% of the time (should be entrain). TX @Jim